# Seeing leaks when using an NSCollectionView

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-leaks, nscollectionview

I have a simple `NSCollectionView` that displays a set of images, each one with a checkbox and a title under it. I've run it with the Leaks profiling tool, and it shows a few leaks. I'm trying to understand where the leaks come from, as none of my code appears in the stack trace for the leak. For example, just displaying a few items in the collection, selecting an image and dismissing the window results in 15 leaked `NSMutableIndexSet` objects. Most of the stack traces for these leaks look like this:

```
0 libsystem_malloc.dylib malloc_zone_calloc
1 libsystem_malloc.dylib calloc
2 libobjc.A.dylib class_createInstance
3 Foundation NSAllocateObject
4 AppKit -[NSCollectionViewLayoutAccessibility _visibleSections]
5 AppKit -[NSCollectionViewLayoutAccessibility _dumpVisibleChildren]
6 AppKit -[NSCollectionViewLayoutAccessibility accessibilityInvalidateLayout]
7 AppKit -[NSCollectionView layout]
8 AppKit -[NSView _doLayout]
9 AppKit -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:]
10 AppKit -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:]
11 AppKit -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:]
12 AppKit -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:]
13 AppKit -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:]
14 AppKit -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:]
15 AppKit -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:]
16 AppKit -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:]
17 AppKit -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:]
18 AppKit -[NSView layoutSubtreeIfNeeded]
19 AppKit -[NSWindow(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutViewTree]
20 AppKit -[NSWindow(NSConstraintBasedLayout) layoutIfNeeded]
21 AppKit ___NSWindowGetDisplayCycleObserver_block_invoke6358
22 AppKit __37+[NSDisplayCycle currentDisplayCycle]_block_invoke
23 QuartzCore CA::Transaction::run_commit_handlers(CATransactionPhase)
24 QuartzCore CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
25 QuartzCore CA::Transaction::commit()
26 QuartzCore CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
27 CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
28 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoObservers
29 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific
30 HIToolbox RunCurrentEventLoopInMode
31 HIToolbox ReceiveNextEventCommon
32 HIToolbox _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter
33 AppKit _DPSNextEvent
34 AppKit -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]
35 AppKit -[NSApplication run]
36 AppKit NSApplicationMain
37 libdyld.dylib start
```

My collection view data source and delegate code is fairly straightforward. I'm at a loss to understand why these are leaking. Can anyone help me understand what's going on here?

My code does allocate some `NSMutableIndexSet` objects, but they are autoreleased instances, so it shouldn't be leaking them. (And also, the stack trace shows that it's not coming from where my code creates them, so it doesn't seem to be related.)

If it makes any difference, I'm using ARC, building my app with Xcode 8.2.1 and running on macOS 10.11.6 (El Capitan).

One or two of the leaks do show 2 lines of my code in the stack trace. Basically, the call to my window controller's `-loadWindow` method shows up in the middle of the stack. The window is not deallocated when these leaks show up, so if it were anything in the window holding on to them, it would still be in memory (and hence not a leak).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is a known leak in El Capitan that is fixed in Sierra, according to [this discussion](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/45487) on Apple's developer forums:

> I'm no longer seeing the leak in when profiling in Instruments in Xcode 8 on Sierra. It looks likey did fix it actually. Thanks Apple